# Please identify this plant with flowers

Tags: identification

This plant grew on its own in my container.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possibly nicotiniana

Comment: Really close to Four O'Clock, but the leaves are alternate, not opposite. Posting a photo with the flower would help. Also, please let us know if the flowers are fragrant.

Comment: I vote for nicotiana. I have many four o'cloks and it is similar but not quite right, they have more random flower clusters.

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler  Yeah, nicotiana (probably N. alata) looks to be the answer (the opposite leaves match up well). The flower would probably clinch it. You should convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: I don’t know which species, you answer.